# Unable to retrieve Geo Reference or coordinates in Forge Viewer for 2D DWG files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have a 2D DWG file that is georeferenced with coordinates and translate the file using forge API.
We load the file on the forge viewer and load Autodesk georeference Extension. (checked on AutoCad 2021 tool as well)

I am trying to retrieve these properties but get

**hasgeoreference** false,

**globaloffset** undefined

Because of this, I am unable to use the LMV LAT functions in the georeference Extension.

could someone tell me if I have missed something...?

Answer (score 1):

What application is your georeferenced DWG coming from? The Forge Model Derivative service supports georeference data coming from Revit 2D sheets but I'm not sure about other applications. Also, if you could privately share one of the DWGs with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, we'd be happy to pass it on to the engineering team and investigate further on our end.